# If $B$ is a subbasis for $T$, $B'$ for $T'$, $C:= B \times B'$ is closed under intersections

Tags: general-topology

If $(X,T), (X',T')$ are topological spaces and $B$ is a subbasis for $T$ and $B'$ is a subbasis for T', then $C:= B \times B'$ is closed under intersections. This is stated without proof in my notes.

So... I would take two arbitrary elements in $C$ say $(X_1, X'_1)$ and 
$(X_2, X'_2)$ and I would have to show that their intersection is in $C$. My question is what if $X_1 \cap X_2$ is not an element in $B$ ? Would this not contradict that $C$ is closed under finite intersections?

Edit: This is part of a theorem : 
Suppose $(X, T )$ and $(X', T')$ are topological spaces. If $B$ is a subbasis for $T$
and $B'$ is a subbasis for $T'$, then $C := B×B'$ is a basis for the product topology on $X \times X'$.

Comment: Yes. . . . . . .

Comment: @WilliamElliot maybe there is a mistake in my notes. In the theorem that I just added in the edit, should the word subbasis be replaced by basis?

Comment: The last theorem is wrong. And $B \times B'$ is not closed under intersections, necessarily.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what If I modify the theorem so that $B$, and $B'$ are basis's (not sure what the plural of basis is).

Comment: Fit bases it is OK, but a product of subbases will not be a base in general.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma not sure what fit bases means?

Comment: fit should be for. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $\mathcal{B}'$ is a base for $(X', \mathcal{T}')$, the set

$$\{B_1 \times B_2: B_1 \in \mathcal{B};  B_2 \in \mathcal{B}'\}$$

is a base for $(X \times X', \mathcal{T} \times \mathcal{T}')$.

The same holds for all subbases as well.

Comment: How is the subbases part of this statement different from what I posted? Sorry I am still a bit confused, but reading Munkres Topology helped.

Comment: @IntegrateThis the product of subbases need not be a base. Just a subbase is then assured.

Comment: OH!! Ok. Now I understand. Should have thought of that. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

No, not even if B and B' are bases.
Let B = {{0}} be a base for {0} and
B' = { {n}, {n,m,q} : distinct n,m,q in N }
be a base for the discrete topology of N.

Of note is that {1,2,3} $\cap$ {2,3,4} is not in B'.
Perhaps if B and B' were minimal bases,
then B×B' would be closed under intersection.

Alternatively, if B and B' are topologies,
then B×B' is intersection closed.

Comment: I believe Munkres introduction to topology gives a theorem stating the accepted answer, is this different than your counter-example?

Comment: Henno showed a 'product' of two bases is a base.  I have shown that a base does not have to be intersection closed even if it is a 'product' of two bases.